# $\phi^4$ loop digram with six legs going out

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams

I want to set up an integral for the following diagram in
$\phi^4$ theory

[image]

my attempt is
\begin{split}
& 15(-i\lambda)^3\iint \frac{d^Dl}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{d^Dq}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{i}{l^2-m^2+i\epsilon}\frac{i}{q^2-m^2+i\epsilon}\frac{i}{(l+q)^2-m^2+i\epsilon}
\end{split}

where there is zero external momentum.

Is the equation I wrote correct?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is my approach to writing the integral representation of the loop correct? Are there other ways to write it?

Comment: @sultana Your external legs do not carry momentum?

Comment: @PraharMitra yes, there is zero external momentum.

Comment: If there is no external momenta, then all the loop propagators have momentum $\ell$ so the denominator should be $\frac{i^3 }{ [ \ell^2 - m^2 + i \epsilon ]^3 }$

Comment: Thanks, @PraharMitra!

Comment: I am wondering where does the 15 come from.

Comment: @sultana The factor of 15 seems wrong. In the combinatorics, (4C2 *2)^3 at each vertex * (3-1)! for circular permutations and 1/2 due to bosonic symmetry. And then (1/4!)^3 due to interactions. So a 1/8 factor should be there instead.